# How to force a Gradle library to use its own version of dependency and not the project's one?

Tags: java, gradle

There are these gradle projects:

- **main project** (that uses **library A** and **library B-version-1**)
- **library A** (that uses **library B-version-2** declared as `api`, so the main project has both versions in dependencies B-v1 and B-v2).

When I run the app, the code from **library A** uses the version of library-B specified in the main project (B-v1), not the one it uses originally (B-v2).

Is there a way to force the library-A to use its own version of library-B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to force the library-A to use its own version of library-B?

Yes, but how you achieve it depends on your goals:

- if you want `library-A` to use its own version of `library-B` AND the main project to use its own version of `library-B` at the same time, you need to use [Java Module System](https://openjdk.org/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/) or do some dangerous tricks with class loading
- if you want to force the version of `library-B` from `library-A` rather than the version from the main project, you just need to tell Gradle a few more words than usual - **this is what my answer will be about**

---

To understand why the `v2` version of `library-B` was choose, you can read this [manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sub:resolution-strategy):

> Gradle will consider all requested versions, wherever they appear in the dependency graph. Out of these versions, it will select the highest one.

##### Assumption #1

*You defined the version of `library-B` yourself and can change it in the main project.*

So just change the version of `library-B` to the version that comes from `library-A` or just delete the dependency declaration `->` the transitive dependency on `library-B` will be used

##### Assumption #2

*You didn't define the version of `library-B` yourself and cannot change it in the main project. For example, this version comes from another library.*

The are several ways to say Gradle which version of `library-B` it should use.

For example, using [rich versions declaration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/rich_versions.html#rich-version-constraints), you define an implementation of `library-B` with the version you prefer:

```
// build.gradle.kts

dependencies {
    implementation("group.name:library-A:v1") // uses 'library-B' version 'v1'
    implementation("group.name:library-C:v1") // uses 'library-B' version 'v2'
    implementation("group.name:library-B") {
        version {
            strictly("v1")
        }
    }
}
```

Or using [resolution strategy configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html):

```
// build.gradle.kts

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "group.name:library-B:v1"
    }
}
```